# How to Always have just a single Instance of a Cloud Run container running

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a NodeJS app hosted on Cloud Run.

I have set that just 1 and only 1 instance of the service should be running at any given point in time.

However, whenever I make a code change and deploys the new revision, it turns out that the previous revision is still running until after a while then it stops.

How can I make sure even though I am deploying new code changes, multiple instances should never run. The existing running instance should stop immediately I am about to deploy new changes.

Multiple instances is causing duplicate items to be produced in my code and business logic.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the value `1` applied for both minimum and maximum instance?

Comment: Yes I set 1 for both Maximum and minimum

Comment: Can you share a screenshot that shows that the previous revision is still running as I tested using both first and second generation and 100% of the traffic is transferred to the new revision when `Serve this revision immediately` option is checked? There's a bit of a delay when deploying the new revision but nonetheless all of the traffic is transferred to the new revision.

Comment: Did my previous comment address your concern?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

- Minimum number of instances:0
- Maximum number of instances: 1
- 'Serve this revision immediately' checkbox is selected.

Based on that, 100% of the traffic will be migrated to the revision, overriding all existing traffic splits, if any.

[image]